# JQuery Find Elements in Proximity to Other Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1">
  <Columns>
     <asp:TemplateField>
       <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:DropDownList></asp:DropDownList> 
           <input type="tel" id="contract">
       </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
     <asp:TemplateField>
       <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:Label><asp:Label>
           <asp:Label><asp:Label>
       </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
     <asp:TemplateField>
       <ItemTemplate>
           <input type="tel" id="Hours">
       </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I am trying to use JQuery as a quick way to validate the template fields in my GridView.  For example, if the SelectedValue of my DropDownList = RENT READY, then the Hours input should not be blank.  So I want to use JQuery to get a count of all times that I can narrow down to a select with a value of RENT READY whose corresponding Hours input = blank.  I've tried:

```
$("#GridView1 select[value=RENT READY]").find("input[type=tel]").eq(1)
```

and

```
$("#GridView1 select[value=RENT READY]").next("input[type=tel]").next("input[type=tel]")
```

and

```
$("#GridView1 select[value=RENT READY]").next("input[type=tel value=''])
```

But always returns undefined.  The select piece works just fine.  It has no problem finding the selects with a value of RENT READY. It's the 2nd piece where I try to narrow it down further to just the selects with an input relative 2 doors down with a blank value that isn't working.

[image]

Edit:  Final Code

```
$('#GridView1 select').filter(function () {
            return ($(this).val() == 'RENT READY');
        }).closest('tr').find('input[type=tel]').filter(function () {
            return ($(this).val() == "" && $(this).attr("id") == "Hours");
        }).length
```

Comment: You should give us the rendered HTML.

Comment: added.  sorry if it is a little small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that is a valid way to select a drop down with value "RENT READY".

You should do it like below,

```
$('#GridView1 select').filter(function () {
    return ($(this).val() == 'RENT READY');
})
```

To get the `tel` find the closest `tr` and do a find.. or you can do `.next .next` on select parent.

```
$('#GridView1 select').filter(function () {
    return ($(this).val() == 'RENT READY');
}).closest('tr').find('input[type=tel]')
```

Comment: Actually wait.  That helped me find the next input, but it's not helping me find how many instances of this are happening in order to validate form.  I changed it to $('#GridView1 select').filter(function () {
                return ($(this).val() == 'RENT READY');
            }).closest('tr').find('input[type=tel]').eq(1).filter(function () {
                return ($(this).val() == "");
            }).length which returns 1 as long as the first table row with RENT READY has blank hours.  But if I put a value there but 3 rows down is also RENT READY with blank hours, it returns 0

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by 3 rows down is also RENT READY.. Do you mean that you have another drop down with value 'RENT READY'? Post your html/show us your case in http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: Yes.  This is a GridView.  Each row will have a DropDown.

Comment: And where is this `input[type=tel]` in each row? Post markup or similar structure..

Comment: I don't think you should use `.eq(1)` as that will always select one element. You want to do a count then use `.size()`

Comment: @Moin Zaman.  I am using eq because there are more than on tel inputs on the row.  I am only interested in what is in the 2nd one and only if it is blank

Comment: @Vega the elements are the same in each row.  They are just databound templatefields that may have different values for each row.  But it is the same elements in the same position every time.

Comment: Your current code is not getting selects with that value. Two problems: First, you need to quote your value, or it throws an exception: http://jsfiddle.net/b9chris/DhpmM/ Second, even if you do quote your value: http://jsfiddle.net/b9chris/DhpmM/3/ It still won't find it, because attribute selectors look for attribute values which are what was set when the page loaded; the current value is a property. You can't use selectors to filter by property - you have to use .filter() or .grep().

Comment: @jmease How many `input[type=tel]` will be there in each row? Is `input[type=tel]` located in `<td>select</td><td>..</td><td>input[type=tel]</td>`? And do you want to check if the value of this input is blank?

Comment: Got it working. Largely thanks to the kick start @Vega gave.  I will add my final code to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

you need to get the option that is selected inside the select. like this:

`$('#GridView1 select#GridViewStatus option[value="RENT READY"]:selected"').closest('input[type="tel"]')`

adding `.size()` at the end will give you 0 if not found or >0 if found.

Comment: The closest tel input is not the one I'm after.  Nor does this help me filter down to just the ones with blank values.

Comment: Ok, how many selects and corresponding inputs do you expect to have in the page? I think you may need to do a `.each()` on the selects and check for the inputs.

Comment: I originally was doing an each, but as the purpose of this is to validate the page and return false if the count is > 0, I was having an issue with the page continuing to postback when the return false statement was inside of the each loop.

Comment: Instead of returning false, you could have a counter and as soon as the counter is greater than 0, then return true or 1. Check for this and then in your validate page function you return false. Does that make sense?